# "Invalid plugin.yml" message on enable of Bukkit plugin

Tags: java, yaml, bukkit

I'm working on my first Bukkit plugin. Here's my `main` class in the `eruverio.EruvPlg` package:

```
package eruverio.EruvPlg;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class main extends JavaPlugin {

}
```

And here's the `plugin.yml`:

```
name: Test
main: eruverio.EruvPlg.main
version: 1.0
```

Project structure:

```
| Project
----| src/main/java
|   ----| eruverio.EruvPlg (Package)
|       ----| main.java
|           ----| main (class)
|
----| src/main/resources
|   ----| plugin.yml
|
----| pom.yml
```

'pom.yml':

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>eruverio.EruvPlg</groupId>
  <artifactId>main</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <source>1.7</source>
                  <target>1.7</target>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
         <id>bukkit-repo</id>
         <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.bukkit</groupId>
           <artifactId>bukkit</artifactId>
           <version>1.7.2-R0.2</version>
           <type>jar</type>
           <scope>provided</scope>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run exported JAR file on a Bukkit server, it throws an exception:

```
    [14:09:14] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not load 'plugins\EruvPlg.jar' in folder 'plugins'
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidDescriptionException: Invalid plugin.yml
at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.getPluginDescription(JavaPluginLoader.java:247) ~[bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:133) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:255) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_7_R1.CraftServer.<init>(CraftServer.java:233) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.PlayerList.<init>(PlayerList.java:63) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.DedicatedPlayerList.<init>(SourceFile:14) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:126) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:424) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
at net.minecraft.server.v1_7_R1.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:617) [bukkit.jar:git-Bukkit-1.7.2-R0.2-b2974jnks]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml

... 9 more
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you include the entire stack trace? Also, could you include the entire `plugin.yml` if the above one isn't complete?

Comment: This is complete plugin.yml file. Updated.

Comment: Aww. I had to move the 'plugin.yml' file from 'resources' to the main project folder.

Comment: Ok, you should answer your own question and say that, and then accept the answer. It'll help others who had the same problem as you

Comment: Instead of editing the answer into your question, you should create an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'plugin.yml' file must be placed in the main folder of the project.

```
| Project
----| src/main/java
|   ----| eruverio.EruvPlg (Package)
|       ----| main.java
|           ----| main (class)
|
----| src/main/resources
|
----| plugin.yml
|
----| pom.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything setup correctly, but based on the last message it looks like it doesn't see your plugin.yml "Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jar does not contain plugin.yml".

Also, is the name of the project Test? I'm pretty sure that the Name: in the plugin.yml must match the actual project name. I only see you referring to the project as Project and not Test.

Answer (score 0):

Some editors don't directly add your plugin.yml... Download it or save it and use a program like 7zip to open it and put it in. If you don't have a plugin.yml, use the bukkit.org wiki to find a full tutorial on how to use it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.